# SQL Order By on Union - Random order on DateTime field

Tags: sql

I've got a query with about 5 unions; at the end I've got an order by on a DateTime field (so I'm 100% definitely not ordering on a varchar) - and it seems the order is screwed up for some reason, any ideas? There's no identifiable pattern either :(

```
SELECT a, b, c, DateField
FROM whatever

UNION

SELECT a, b, c, DateField
FROM whatever

UNION

SELECT a, b, c, DateField
FROM whatever

Order By convert(DateTime, DateField, 111) -- The convert is just to make doubly sure about the data type
```

Comment: Could you add some example data?  Which database are you using?

Comment: I've just realized that even if i comment out the order by it's still in the same state - nothing changes at all?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a, b, c, DateField FROM 
(SELECT a, b, c, DateField
FROM whatever

UNION

SELECT a, b, c, DateField
FROM whatever

UNION

SELECT a, b, c, DateField
FROM whatever) x
Order By DateField
```

Comment: This should only be required in MySQL.  In standard SQL, the order by affects all statements in the union, and an order by is only allowed at the end of the union.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't do like this (I am not sure whether you really want to use 
style 111 = Japan standard = yy/mm/dd. Think better if you use 
`style 103 = dd/MM/yyyy`).

```
select *
from
(
SELECT a, b, c, convert(DateTime, DateField, 103) as mydate FROM whatever  
UNION  
SELECT a, b, c, convert(DateTime, DateField, 103) as mydate FROM whatever  
UNION  
SELECT a, b, c, convert(DateTime, DateField, 103) as mydate FROM whatever  
)
Order By mydate
```